# Difference between ng-model and angular expression - {{}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

{{}} is working fine but ng-model is not, at the same place.

I am using the following html-

```
<body ng-app="crud">
  Gray input fields will not be visible.
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" value="sdf" ng-model="asdf"/>
    <h1 ng-model="asdf"></h1>   <!-- this doesn't work-->
    <h1>{{asdf}}</h1>           <!-- this work-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

asdf is defined in this js app like this

```
 var app = angular.module("crud", []);
 app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.asdf="ankur";
 }]);
```

Can someone explain why is it so ?

Comment: you should use `ng-bind` instead of `ng-model` for one way binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ng-model directive is to be used on the input fields such as input, select for two way data binding and to get an input from a user.

Where as the one way data binding expression {{}} or ng-bind directive is used to output the data in the view.

```js
var app = angular.module("crud", []);
app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.asdf="ankur";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="crud">
  Gray input fields will not be visible.
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" value="sdf" ng-model="asdf"/>
    <h1 ng-bind="asdf"></h1>
    <h1>{{asdf}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-bind` for display purposes, instead of `ng-model`.

```
<h1 ng-bind="asdf"></h1>
```

You only want to use `ng-model` when binding to an element that will be editing the variable, such as a text field.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

> The `ngModel` directive binds an `input`, `select`, `textarea` (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), which is created and exposed by this directive.

You are trying to use it on a `<h1>`. Use [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) instead.

Answer (score 0):

According the doc

```
the ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.
```

so you will not use it for display an `H1`

For the brackets they will be dirty checked and refreshed in every $digest, even if it's not necessary. So it's slower. Plus thez may appear while your angularjs is bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

**ng-model** : This directive binds the values of AngularJS application data to HTML input controls.

**{{}}**  This use For Printing purpose only. you can put expression also like  {{2*2}}  it prints 4

Refer This for study basic syntax   https://angularjs.org/